# Turn rows into column and then left join to another query

Tags: oracle

I have a table called Responses where the values are like this:

| Client ID | Response Code | Response Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10047 | RA13 | University Degree |
| 10047 | RA14 | Married |
| 10047 | RA15 | Hispanic |
| 10047 | RA16 | Employment |
| 10047 | RA17 | January 29, 1987 |

I would like to turn the response values in the above table into columns like this:

| Client ID | Education level | Marital Status | Race | Income Source | Date of Birth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10047 | University Degree | Married | Hispanic | Employment | January 29, 1987 |

and then I would like to LEFT JOIN this query to another query that has multiple joins already. I was wondering if anyone could help me write this query so that I can left join it to another query?

Please note: I have 10,877 distinct Client IDs in my response table

Thank you!

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: @BobbyDurrett Version 7.3.3.202101161839. I am using DBeaver

Comment: That is not an Oracle Database version - it must be your DBeaver version (which has nothing to do with Oracle version). If you don't know your Oracle version, run `select * from v$version` and see what it says. The version must be a five-part number, like 11.2.0.4.0.

Comment: @mathguy ahh thank you here is the oracle version number: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select .....
from   .....
       left outer join
       ( select client_id, education_level, marital_status, race, income_source,
                to_date(date_of_birth, 'Month dd, yyyy') as date_of_birth
         from   responses
         pivot  (min(response_value) 
                 for response_code in ( RA13 as education_level,
                                        RA14 as marital_status,
                                        RA15 as race,
                                        RA16 as income_source,
                                        RA17 as date_of_birth
                                      )
                )
       ) q
              on some_table.client_id = q.client_id
  ............
```

One thing to note - in the subquery I also used `TO_DATE` to convert the date of birth to the proper data type. You may choose to skip that step if you like poor practices.

Comment: haha I will take your advice and convert to 'Month dd, yyyy'! Just wondering is there any reason you chose min(response value) instead of max(response value)?

Comment: @ops_mltsd - **pivot** is, in fact, an aggregate operation (you may consolidate and summarize several rows into one, while "pivoting" at the same time). When you use `pivot` simply to put all the values in a row, each aggregate function applies to one value at a time. It shouldn't be `avg` or such, since usually you have strings. That leaves `min` and `max`. You could use either one, since they apply to **a single value** - there is no difference between `min` and `max` when applied to a single value.

Comment: thank you for the explanation! your query works perfectly, the only problem is, my total count now has suddenly become 924,750. I do notice that there are multiple rows of the client ids though, not sure what happened

Comment: i think the problem is, because for example, client 10047 answered 103 questions in the response table, they are appearing 103 times in the new query, is there a way to control for that?

Comment: @ops_mltsd - Run just the "pivot subquery" by itself and see what it returns. Then: if by "questions" you mean 103 different rows in the input table (one per response code), some with the codes you showed us and some for other codes, that shouldn't cause any problem; codes OTHER THAN those you showed us would simply be ignored. What you report would be caused by something else: other **columns** in the input, which you didn't mention. Are there other columns in the input (in this one table)?

Comment: yes there are other columns in the response table as well. by "run the pivot subquery by itself" do you mean the query you just posted above? I ran that one only first before left joining to another table. When I run the query you posted above, I get 924,750 rows

Comment: @ops_mltsd - The "other columns" are the culprit. In the query I wrote, instead of `from responses`, you should use a sub-sub-subquery like this: 'from (select client_id, response_code, response_value from responses where response_code in ('RA13', 'RA14', 'RA15', 'RA16', 'RA17'))`. Thus reducing the table just to the three columns (and, while at it, just to the codes you want in the output). The reason for what you noticed is that `pivot` is a hidden form of aggregation - it "groups by" **all** columns except those mentioned in the `pivot` clause.

Comment: To group only by `client_id`, and not also, for example, by a "timestamp" column (that may have different values in each row even for a single client), you must first get rid of the other columns, in a sub-subquery as I suggested above. Write it with this sub-subquery and again run just the pivot subquery by itself, before joining to the rest - just to make sure it produces what you need.

Comment: so basically instead of writing "from responses" I write 'from (select client_id, response_code, response_value from responses where response_code in ('RA13', 'RA14', 'RA15', 'RA16', 'RA17'))" in my query? and then do the PIVOT function?

Comment: it works! thank you so much for your help! really appreciate it!